# How to pass Matlab variable to Java Arrays.asList for MongoDB Java driver

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb, matlab

I'm working with Matlab to interface a Java driver and I need to pass an array of values. The Java driver is for MongoDB. In Matlab I start by creating a document

```
Doc = Document();
```

then pass it to MongoDB via the Java driver

```
Doc.append('X',Arrays.asList({239.23042,-8328.20923}))
coll.insertOne(Doc);
```

and it writes to the database as intended. I check the array output in Matlab by typing in

```
Arrays.asList({239.23042,-8328.20923})
```

which returns

```
[239.23042, -8328.20923]
```

I also checked the class

```
class(Arrays.asList({239.23042,-8328.20923}))
```

which returns

```
java.util.Arrays$ArrayList
```

Now I need this concept to work with a large Matlab array. For the purpose of this question, I tried to pass a Matlab variable

```
apple = [239.23042,-8328.20923];
Doc.append('X',Arrays.asList({apple}))
coll.insertOne(Doc);
```

and I get a very long error message, that starts with

```
Java exception occurred:
org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class [D.
```

I double backed and checked the array output in Matlab by typing in

```
Arrays.asList({apple})
```

all it returns

```
[[D@22144d03]
```

which starts with the `[D` that the error is complaining about (I don't know what it is). I then tried to check the class in Matlab

```
class(Arrays.asList({apple}))
```

which shows

```
java.util.Arrays$ArrayList
```

I'm confused on how to properly create a Java array in Matlab to pass through the driver on to MongoDB. How do I get the latter variable case to output the same as the former explicit case?

Supplemental info:

I imported the following before attempting anything

```
import com.mongodb.*;
import org.bson.Document;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
```

Matlab release 2013a

MongoDB v3.4

Java driver v3.6

Java skills = weak

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some trial and error, I found a solution that works. That being said, I'm not sure if it's the best solution so I'm not going to accept my own answer right away. Maybe someone with more experience can show a better solution.

As I suspected, it seems to be the way Matlab interfaces with Java. Again, these are uncharted waters for me. Anyway, here's what I did

```
dblArray = javaArray('java.lang.Double',1);
for n = 1:length(apple)
    dblArray(n) = java.lang.Double(apple(n));
end
Doc.append('X',Arrays.asList(dblArray));
coll.insertOne(Doc);
```

Note that there is no `{}` around `apple` as I was trying earlier